# Android Studio Animation Using ObjectAnimation

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

I've been trying to animate a button but none of the animations work on it. I'm not trying to animate something after something has been clicked. I want to animate it when this function is called. Does anybody know why my button refuses to animate?

```
private void eliminate() {
    for (int i = 0; i == 0; i++) {
        int randomJ = getRandomNumberInRange(0, 2);
        int randomI = getRandomNumberInRange(0, 2);

        if (!buttons[randomI][randomJ].getText().toString().equals("")) {
            buttons[randomI][randomJ].setText("");

            objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buttons[randomI][randomJ], "rotation", 180);
            objectAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buttons[randomI][randomJ], "alpha", 1);

            objectAnimator.setDuration(5000);

        } else {
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have not added the ***.start()*** method to your animation. 
Below is a simple example I made with a layout that has one TextView element with the id "textview":

```
 TextView animateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

 ObjectAnimator textViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animateTextView, "translationY",0f,500f);
 textViewAnimator.setDuration(2000);
 textViewAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
 textViewAnimator.start();
```

You can read more in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) or see a good example [here](https://medium.com/@shubham.bestfriendforu/a-beginners-guide-to-implement-android-animations-part-1-2-part-series-b5fce1fc85)